# Enabling intellisense in groovysh

Tags: python, groovy, command-line, groovyshell

Is it possible to enable intellisense in groovysh, in similar lines of what python offering?

Code completion feature is not working in groovysh at all.

So far there was a myth that command arrows will not work. But after refering documentation and using the below command they are working in Windows 10.

```
groovysh --terminal=none
```

Similarly is there any option for code completion as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative. If you use Windows Powershell, code completion works in groovy. You can type any command and use tab to code completion. It was not working on plain command shell.

The only tradeoff I found in Powershell (with groovysh) is: arrowkeys won't work. However you can use Ctrl P and Ctrl N.